# Why does geoserver layer disappear when baselayer is false?

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, openstreetmap

I am trying to overlay a layer from Geoserver on an OpenStreetMap base layer.  If I load the Geoserver layer as a base layer, I can see it - but if I set baselayer to false it disappears.

My code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>OpenLayers Demo</title>
    <style type="text/css">
      html, body, #basicMap {
          width: 100%;
          height: 100%;
          margin: 0;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="../OpenLayers-2.13.1/OpenLayers.js"></script>
    <script>
      function init() {
       map = new OpenLayers.Map("basicMap");
        var mapnik         = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM({transparent:true});

        map.addLayer(mapnik);

        map.addLayer(new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS("Test Addresses","http://localhost:8080/geoserver/os_lv/wms",{layers: 'os_lv:test_addresses',transparent: true},{ isBaseLayer: false,opacity: 0.5})) ;
//      map.addLayer(new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS("Test Addresses","http://localhost:8080/geoserver/os_lv/wms",{layers: 'os_lv:test_addresses',transparent: true},{opacity: 0.5})) ;

        map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher()) ;            
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="init();">
    <div id="basicMap"></div>
    <p id="shortdesc">
        Shows the basic use of openlayers using a WMS layer
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

I've used firebug to investigate the calls being made to geoserver.  In the case where I add the WMS as a base layer I see the following:

```
 <img class="olTileImage" style="visibility: inherit; opacity: 0.5; position: 
   absolute; left: 664px; top: 81px; width: 256px; height: 256px;" 
   src="http://localhost:8080/geoserver/os_lv/wms? 
   LAYERS=os_lv%3Atest_addresses&TRANSPARENT=TRUE&SERVICE=WMS
   &VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetMap&STYLES=&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&SRS=EPSG%3A4326 
   &BBOX=-3.4157819747925,50.611286201963,-3.3442823886872,50.682785788068
   &WIDTH=256&HEIGHT=256" id="null">
```

whereas when baselayer is false it's

```
<img class="olTileImage" style="visibility: inherit; opacity: 0.5; position: 
      absolute; left: 773px; top: 16px; width: 256px; height: 256px;" 
      src="http://localhost:8080/geoserver/os_lv/wms?
      LAYERS=os_lv%3Atest_addresses&TRANSPARENT=TRUE&SERVICE=WMS
      &VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetMap&STYLES=&FORMAT=image%2Fpng
      &SRS=EPSG%3A900913&BBOX=-180,-90,2265.9849047852,2355.9849047852
      &WIDTH=256&HEIGHT=256">
```

The first call returns a PNG showing my data, the second one is empty.

A final point is that my data in Geoserver has native SRS EPSG:4258 and declared SRS EPSG:4326 - I have set the "Reproject native to declared" option.

Answer (score 1):

When there is no baselayer set you don't get an SRS and bounds set in the map by default. Hence you are requesting and very small map of [Null Island](http://www.nullisland.com/) so probably don't see anything. So look at setting a projection (SRS) and bounds for the map object if you don't want to supply a base map for it to work from.